# How do i reference an array as a whole?- php

Tags: php

array_unique is to be used by passing the array name as a parameter.

But as far as all the online examples researched go, it shows the arrays first being assigned to a single variable at the time they are instantiated, like so:

```
$var1 = $array['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

The only problem is, i am assigning the values of my array 1 at a time via a loop, so i dont know how to assign my array as a whole to a variable.

So how can i represent the entire array to either put in a variable or pass as a parameter for array_unique directly, without having to reference the specific array values?

Edit: Added the loop where array values are instantiated, as requested.

```
$productsQueryResult = mysql_query($productsQuery);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($productsQueryResult))
            {
                $array[$i] = $row[0];
                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: Can you show me your loop code where you are assigning array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass name of the array as parameter:

```
array_unique( $array );
```

Comment: That's so straightforward, i should have thought of that, lol. You get my vote, for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

While looping, you can append the value as the last element of the array as:

```
loop-statement
{
    ...

    $arr[] = value;

    ...
}
```

Then, you can use the `$arr` variable in any array processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productsQueryResult = mysql_query($productsQuery);

$array = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($productsQueryResult))
{
    $array[] = $row[0];
}

$unique_array = array_unique( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$productsQueryResult = mysql_query($productsQuery);
$temp = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($productsQueryResult))
{
    //process $row value
    array_push($temp, $row[0]); 
}

$newarray = array_unique($temp);
```